# How do I implement Electron's webview into my Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, webview, electron

I have the following code, but when I run my applications and look at the dev tools, webview tags are in the DOM, but nothing shows up on my screen...

```
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webviewTag: true,
    width: 1276, 
    height: 800, 
    frame: false, 
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    center: true, 
    movable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
}

In my component: 

<webview id="foo" src="https://www.youtube.com/" style="display:inline-flex; width:640px; height:480px"></webview>
```

[dev tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9wYr.png)

Comment: can you share the dev tools console?

Comment: @tpikachu I uploaded an image.

Comment: Oh, man. I need the console image

Comment: This is Elements tab. You can see the Console tab on the top of the dev tools

Comment: ah my bad... one second.

Comment: But also there's nothing to show, but I added it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1276, 
    height: 800, 
    frame: false, 
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    center: true, 
    movable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webviewTag: true,
    }
  })
```

`webviewTag` is a field of `webPreferences`

Comment: Okay, I changed it to webPreferences, but has same result. in DOM and no console messages.

Comment: That's interesting... it kinda works. I have to launch electron and search for webviews in dev tools before it renders the webview... know a solution to render on launch?

Comment: hey did you get the answer? i'm also looking for the solutions, documentation is not helping!

Comment: @tpikachu strangely, it is not working with angular project but working with plain electron project

Comment: your electorn version is?